# How to filter a list of objects by a list of ids?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Let's say we have a list of objects like this:

```
my_objects = [
    {
        "id":0,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
]
```

Given a list of ids like this:

```
ids = [1, 2]
```

What would be a pythonic way to retrieve a list of all the objects with the ids in this list?
e.g.:

```
my_objects_filtered = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "some_value":"b"
    }
]
```

What I want in the end is a list of the "some_value" value for all ids in the list "ids":

```
ids = [a, b]
```

Which I could get by doing this:

```
some_values = [my_object.param_id for my_object in my_objects_filtered]
```

But I do not know how to get `my_objects_filtered`
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the below

```
my_objects = [
    {
        "id": 0,
        "some_value": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "some_value": "a"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "some_value": "b"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "some_value": "b"
    },
]
ids = [1, 2]
final_list = [x['some_value'] for x in my_objects if x['id'] in ids]
print(final_list)
```

output

```
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like so :

```py
my_objects = [
    {
        "id":0,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
]
id_to_select = [1 ,2]
my_objects_filtered = [obj["some_value"] for obj in my_objects if obj["id"] in id_to_select]
print(my_objects_filtered) 
# [{'id': 1, 'some_value': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'some_value': 'b'}]
```

But i'm not sure if it's the pythonic way

Perhaps using filter with lambda is better :

```py
my_objects = [
    {
        "id":0,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":1,
        "some_value":"a"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "some_value":"b"
    },
]
id_to_select = [1 ,2]
my_objects_filtered = list(map(lambda obj: obj["some_value"],filter(lambda obj: obj["id"] in id_to_select, my_objects)))
print(my_objects_filtered)
# ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a neat optional `if` part list comprehensions:

```
[obj["some_value"] for obj in my_objects if obj["id"] in ids]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ids = [x.get("some_value") for x in my_objects if x['id'] in ids]

#print(ids)
['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you know for a fact that `id` and `some_value` will be in every dict then you can use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
from operator import itemgetter

get_id_val = itemgetter("id", "some_value")

result = [val for i, val in map(get_id_val, my_objects) if i in ids]
```

If you also know that they will be in order and the dicts only have the 2 keys then you could just map `dict.values` instead:

```
[val for i, val in map(dict.values, my_objects) if i in ids]
```

If they are in order but may have more keys then just throw a catch all variable in:

```
[val for i, val, *_ in map(dict.values, my_objects) if i in ids]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```py
my_objects_filtered = [obj for obj in my_objects if obj["id"] in ids]
some_values = [obj["some_value"] for obj in my_objects_filtered]
```